# Find the trajectory of a Particle moving in a rotating tube

Tags: newtonian-mechanics

**Problem:**

A straight smooth tube revolves with angular velocity $\omega$ in a horizontal plane about one extremity which is fixed. If at $t=0$ a particle inside it be at a distance $a$ from a fixed end and moving with a velocity $V$ along the tube, show that its distance at time $t$ is $$r=a\cosh(\omega t)+\frac{V}{t}\sinh(\omega t)$$

**My attempt:**

The radial acceleration is given as follows: $$\ddot r-r\dot{\theta}^2=\frac{V}{t}$$ Since $\dot{\theta}=\omega$, we get: $$\ddot{r}-\omega^2r=\frac{V}{t}$$

However, a quick check reveals that the correct differential equation is indeed $$\ddot r=r\dot{\theta}^2$$How can one justify this given that the particle's velocity is radial velocity is changing direction?

If we use the fact that $$\ddot r=r\dot{\theta}^2=r\omega^2$$ is true, then this, on solving yields $$\dot{r}^2=r^2\omega^2+C$$ Now on putting the initial condition: At $t=0$, $\dot{r}=V$ and $r=a$, we get $C=V^2-a^2\omega^2$.
This implies: $$\dot{r}^2=r^2\omega^2+V^2-a^2\omega^2$$I've solved this ODE but it is nowhere close the solution. Please help.

Comment: You should try to find the radial equation using the Lagrangian formalism.